# Laravel. I can't show data from relation

Tags: php, laravel

i have strange problem. dd(), It shows me that I got to the data, but i cant display single record from table.

I want to get to the name of my role but i get this error :

> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

**Model - User**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

**Controller**

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();
return view('pages.user', compact('users'));
```

**View**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        {{$user->id}}
        <br>
        {{$user->name}}
        <br>
        {{$user->email}}
        <br>
        {{$user->roles->name}}  //this not working
        <br>
        <br>
    @endforeach
```

When Im using `{{$user->roles}}` I get

> {"id":1,"name":"Admin","description":"this is admin","pivot":{"user_id":2,"role_id":1}}]

what Im doing wrong?
Thx for help.

Comment: Maybe is the {{$user->name}} that has problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$user->roles` return a collection as it's defined as a `belongsToMany` relation and you cannot access `name` from it.

Either you have to iterate through the collection or get the first one.

`$user->roles->first()->name`

or

```
@foreach ($user->roles as $role)
    {{ $role->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

`$user->roles` is a collection of elements, you are trying to get a property on a list of elements.

You could use [`implode`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-implode) for example to display all roles comma seperated.

```
{{ $user->roles->implode('name', ', ') }}
```